# Emacs via X: how to use better rendered true type fonts?

Tags: debian, emacs, fonts, xemacs

I have attached a screenshot of Emacs 24.5 running in X-Quartz in a Debian VM.  Does anyone know how to configure Emacs to use the better rendered Andale font?  For instance, with rendering like the ones Mac Terminal.app, where the edges are smoother.

I selected Andale Mono for the Emacs default font, however the edges are jagged in Emacs while smooth in Terminal.app.  I tried Gnome Font viewer and it has jagged edges as well.  Is the font hinting not working correctly or is this as expected for Linux?

[image: 1]

```
 $ dpkg -l|grep emacs
ii  emacs24                               24.5+1-11+deb9u1                            amd64        GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ GUI support)
ii  emacs24-bin-common                    24.5+1-11+deb9u1                            amd64        GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent files
ii  emacs24-common                        24.5+1-11+deb9u1                            all          GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture independent infrastructure
ii  emacs24-el                            24.5+1-11+deb9u1                            all          GNU Emacs LISP (.el) files
ii  emacs25                               25.1+1-4+deb9u1                             amd64        GNU Emacs editor (with GTK+ GUI support)
ii  emacs25-bin-common                    25.1+1-4+deb9u1                             amd64        GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture dependent files
ii  emacs25-common                        25.1+1-4+deb9u1                             all          GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture independent infrastructure
ii  emacs25-el                            25.1+1-4+deb9u1                             all          GNU Emacs LISP (.el) files
ii  emacsen-common                        2.0.8                                       all          Common facilities for all emacsen
```

Comment: I suspect XQuartz (MacOS) and the font render libraries in the VM (expecting a Linux X server, not XQuartz) don't work that well together... possibly they expect X extensions XQuartz doesn't have.